# I have problems importing tables from DUMP files into an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, dump, impdp

This is the first time I work with dump files, I am very beginner at this.

So,
I have DUMP files that contain tables and I need to import those tables to an Oracle database.

This is how my client generated the dump files:

- there are several categories (let's say HR, Finance, Sales, etc..) and for each category, he made SQL queries (where each query is related to one table). Let's continue the reasoning with one category that we will call A.
- For the A category, he generated dump files for the results of all the queries he made. so we have something like that :

  Category A :

  - Table_1
  - Table_2
  - Table_3
  - Table_4

Dump files generated (the number of dmp files depends on the size of the data):

- CategorieA_01.dmp
- CategorieA_02.dmp
- CategorieA_03.dmp
- CategorieA_04.dmp
- CategorieA_05.dmp

So we don't know which table is contained in which dump file. And what I need is to import individual tables into an Oracle Database.

This is what I did. In the command prompt :

```
C:\"path">sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
SQL> Grant dba to my_user;
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY Dir_Name AS 'G:\Dir_Name';  -- This is where I copied all the dmp files and the logs
```

Normally I need to create a tablespace, but with the information I have I don't find anywhere the name of the tablespace for the table I need to import, so what I do is that I write the import statement line and wait for it to return the error saying that it doesn't find the tablespace 'X' and after that I create the tablespace 'X' and I repeat the import statement line as follow (if you have an idea of how I can find the name of the tablespace I need to create without proceeding that way please let me know) :

```
C:\"paths">impdp my_user/pswd TABLES=SYSADM.table_1 directory=Dir_Name dumpfile=CategorieA_.%U.dmp logfile=Log_Name
```

So after this, I had two cases results :

1. The table is successfully loaded : x lines loaded out of x ! ok nice nothing to say.
2. I get this error :

> ORA-02374: conversion error loading table "SYSADM"."Table_1"
> ORA-12899: value too large for column COL_1 (actual: 19, maximum: 18)

So here what I do is that I go back to sql developer and **drop** (linked with #b below) the table_1 that has been created with the missing data and do the following in the prompt command :

Step 1 : I import only the metadata :

```
C:\> impdp my_user/pswd DIRECTORY=Dir_Name DUMPFILE=CategorieA_.%U.dmp CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY TABLES=SYSADM.table_1 LOGFILE=file_name
```

Step 2 : then back to sql developer to extend the size of the column(s):

```
alter table Table_1 modify (COL_1 VARCHAR2(50));
```

Step 3 : Then back to the command prompt to import only the data:

```
impdp my_user/pswd DIRECTORY=Dir_Name DUMPFILE=CategorieA_.%U.dmp CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLES=SYSADM.table_1 LOGFILE=file_name
```

Here again, if you have any advice on how I can import the table without getting this column size error message it would be great.

Now until now nothing was blocking, I always found ways to keep going even if it's taking too much time.

Now when I do this I get two cases as well :

1. All is good, it works perfectly!
2. (b) All the way before wanting to drop the table created in sql developer, I get an error message saying that the table doesn't exist.

So okay, I try to go further with the three steps and right after executing the step 1 I get this this error message :

> error : ORA-39151: Table "SYSADM"."Table_1" exists. All dependent metadata and data will be skipped due to table_exists_action of skip

How is it possible? Oracle says it doesn't exist and at the same time in the command prompt it says it exists.

What's the solution to this?

Thank you if you have read until here I know it was long, but it was only to make it clear to you so that you can see clearly what the problem is.

I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a mismatch between character set of the database which exported the data and your database.

> ORA-02374: conversion error loading table "SYSADM"."Table_1"

One way to handle this would be:

1. Capture the DDL the import will create. Use the `sqlfile` parameter e.g. `SQLFILE=Dir_Name:CategorieA_01.dmp`. The fact that you have so many dump files obviously means this step may be a bit of nause; maybe you can use the wild card here - I don't know, I have never tried it.
2. Comb through the generated DDL files, see what tablespaces are referenced and create them.
3. You can also extract the CREATE TABLE statements. Edit the table definitions, replacing the BYTE semantics with CHAR for all the VARCHAR2 columns. Create the tables.
4. Then import just the data. Run impdp with CONTENT=DATA_ONLY.

The alternative to step is to:

1. Import the **table structures** only. Use the CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY parameter
2. Amend the imported table structures with ALTER TABLE statements to switch to CHAR semantics. Perhaps this is the more tedious option.

---

If you have regular dealings with this client you suggest to them that they do their exports in a more sensible fashion. Perhaps one file per table. Or just one file. All this pfaffing around benefits nobody.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As I am very beginner to all of this, can you explain more how I can do this :

2.Amend the imported table structures with ALTER TABLE statements to switch to CHAR semantics. Perhaps this is the more tedious option.

Thank you in advance

Comment: After you have created the tables you can query USER_TAB_COLS to find the tables and columns which have VARCHAR2 definitions. You can generate the ALTER TABLE  statements from that view.

Comment: Thank you.
I just tried this : 
select column_name, data_type
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'Table_01'
order by column_id
But it gave me empty results

Comment: By default in Oracle identifiers are in UPPER CASE. So try `where table_name = 'TABLE_01' `

Comment: Well if you think the name is in mixed case (which is poor practice) you'll need to wrap it in double-quotes whenever you reference the table (and that's why it's frowned upon as a naming practice). So, `where table_name = '"Table_01"' `

Comment: It still doesn't work, the table is originally in UPPER CASE.

I thought of importing all the metadata and replacing all the varchar2(x) into varchar2(50) is there a query that can do that?

Comment: You *have* created `table_01` haven't you?

Comment: Yes I did (by impdp)

Comment: Do you know of any query that can allow me to do that: Replace all the varchar2(x) into varchar2(50) for example?
I searched in the internet but didn't find anything.
Thank you in advance

Comment: *"Yes I did (by impdp) "* - Is the user you connecting as the user the same as you're using to check the data dictionary? If not, you're need to search the ALL_TAB_COLS view (additionally restricting by owner). *"Do you know of any query that can allow me to do that: Replace all the varchar2(x) into varchar2(50) for example?"*. Nope, that would be magic. You'll need to generate a script from the data dictionary.

Comment: I tried the ALL_TAB_COLS too and the results are still empty.. well never mind I'm doing all the replacement manually, takes a long time but that's all I can for now
Thank you very much !!